QgsLayerTreeView after programatically change selectedLayler not refresh
I have Treeview
    self.root = self.project.layerTreeRoot()
    self.model = QgsLayerTreeModel(self.root)
    self.model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.AllowNodeReorder)
    self.model.setFlag(QgsLayerTreeModel.AllowNodeChangeVisibility)
    self.view = QgsLayerTreeView()
    self.view.setModel(self.model)
     # self.view.currentLayerChanged.connect(lambda: self.zmenaVrstvy(self.view.currentLayer()))
    self.view.currentLayerChanged.connect(self.zmenaVrstvy)
    self.view.collapseAll()
    ...

and programatically change Selected or current layer
def zmenaVrstvy(self):
    ... 
    self.view.setCurrentLayer(self.aktualnaVrstva)
    ...
      

mark is not refresh in self.view.
I want not to switch the layer to another via TreeView when it is set as editable.
See picture. It should be marked layer "body"


What does your zmenaVrstvy method look like?

It is a bit more complicated, but the important thing is that when it finds that the layer it is leaving from is editable, it switches it back
self.view.setCurrentLayer(self.aktualnaVrstva)

Here is the full method
    def zmenaVrstvy(self):
    if self.ukoncenieProgramu == False:
        if self.aktualnaVrstvaVratena == False:
            zmenenaVrstva = self.view.currentLayer()
            if self.aktualnaVrstva is not None:
                if self.aktualnaVrstva.isEditable():
                    # self.mojePlatno.setCurrentLayer(self.aktualnaVrstva)
                    self.aktualnaVrstvaVratena = True
                    self.view.setCurrentLayer(self.aktualnaVrstva)
                else:
                    self.aktualnaVrstva = zmenenaVrstva
                    self.nastrojIdentifikacia.resetujPocitadloPlochy()
                    self.nastrojIdentifikacia.vymaz_vybery()
                    self.nastrojIdentifikacia.vymaz_zvyraznenia()
                    self.nastrojZmazBody.vymaz_vybery()
                    #self.nastrojZmazBody.vymaz_zvyraznenia()
                    if zmenenaVrstva.type() == 0:
                        self.radioButtonM.setEnabled(True)
                        if zmenenaVrstva.featureCount() > 0:
                            if self.zoomToLayer == 1:
                                self.providerMenu.zoom100()
                        self.vyber_widget.setVisible(True)
                        self.pocetParamPrvku = self.zobrazDetailPrvku.nastavPrvok(zmenenaVrstva, self.frameParamPrvku, self.layoutIdentForm)
                        if self.pocetParamPrvku > 1 and self.tlacidloIdentifikacia.isChecked():
                            self.dockParamPrvku.setVisible(True)
                            self.dockParamPrvku.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
                            #self.dockParamPrvku.setMaximumHeight(self.pocetParamPrvku * 27)
                        else:
                            self.dockParamPrvku.setVisible(False)
                            self.vyber_widget.setVisible(False)
                        self.nastrojIdentifikacia.nastav_hladanie(self.vystup_z_elpozu, self.mojePlatno, zmenenaVrstva, self.typVyberuPrvku, self.pocetParamPrvku, self.zobrazDetailPrvku)
                        self.nastrojZmazBody.nastavVrstvu(zmenenaVrstva)
                        self.nastrojEditujPrvok.nastavVrstvu(zmenenaVrstva)
                        self.nastrojPresunVertex.nastavVrstvu()
                    if zmenenaVrstva.type() == 1:
                        self.vyber_widget.setVisible(False)
                        self.dockParamPrvku.setVisible(False)
                        self.pan()
                        if self.zoomToLayer == 1:
                            self.providerMenu.zoom100()
                    self.aktualizujTlacitka("zmenaVrstvy")
                    zmenenaVrstva.reload()
                    self.mojePlatno.refresh()
            else:
                self.aktualnaVrstva = zmenenaVrstva
                self.aktualizujTlacitka("zmenaVrstvy")
            self.nastav_status_butonHladaj()
            utils.info("Aktívna vrstva zmenená na: {}".format(self.view.currentLayer()))
        else:
            self.aktualnaVrstvaVratena = False
            zmenenaVrstva = self.view.currentLayer()
            # self.view.currentNode().setName(zmenenaVrstva.name())
            # aaa = self.view.selectedLayers()

            zmenaVrstvy_msg = "Aktuálna vrstva '{}' sa práve edituje. Najskôr ukončite editáciu !".format(zmenenaVrstva.name())
            msg = QMessageBox()
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Question)
            # msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
            msg.addButton("OK", QMessageBox.YesRole)
            msg.addButton("Nie", QMessageBox.NoRole)
            msg.setText(zmenaVrstvy_msg)
            msg.setWindowTitle("Varovanie")
            vyber = msg.exec_()
            vybrVrstva = self.view.selectedLayers()
            vybrVrstvaNode = self.view.selectedNodes()
            aaa = self.view.currentLegendNode()
            
            # zmenenaVrstva.reload()
            # self.mojePlatno.refresh()
            utils.info("Aktívna vrstva vrátená späť na: {}".format(zmenenaVrstva))
    else:
        utils.info("Program sa ukončuje -- signál po zmene vrstvy odpojený")


nobody can advise me,
I looked at both TreeView and canvas values ​​and everything is OK. In the panel, the "body" layer is correctly marked with a black frame, but the blue marking is a poorly colored layer on which I clicked "kraje".


This is not an answer.
